# jquery image random on home.body

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to get a random background image to load on my wordpress site home page every time the page is loaded or refreshed. Here is the code I have so far:

This is the code I have in my style sheet.

style.css

```
body.home {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;}
```

This is the code I have on my home.php file.

home.php

```
<script>
      var randomImage = {
        paths: [
          "images/home-bg/website-background1.jpg",
          "images/home-bg/website-background2.jpg",
          "images/home-bg/website-background3.jpg",
          "images/home-bg/website-background4.jpg",
          "images/home-bg/website-background5.jpg",
          "images/home-bg/website-background6.jpg",
          "images/home-bg/website-background7.jpg",
        ],
        generate: function(){
          var path = randomImage.paths[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.paths.length)];
          var img = new Image();
          img.src = path;
          $("body.home").html(img);
          $("body.home").attr("href", path);
        }
      }
      randomImage.generate();
</script>
```

If you would like to check out the website its http://americasfinestlighting.com/

Thanks, 
William

Comment: instead of `$("body.home")` separate `body` from `.home` `$("body .home").html(img);`, this works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by adding a snip-it of php to my functions.php file.

```
add_filter('body_class','random_background_images');
function random_background_images($classes) {

    // Generate Random number from 1 to 7.  
    $background_class = 'background_' . rand(1,7);

    $classes[] = $background_class;

    return $classes;
}
```

Then I changed my CSS to the following:

```
body.home.background_1 {
    background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background1.jpg");
}
body.home.background_2 {
    background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background2.jpg");
}
body.home.background_3 {
    background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background3.jpg");
}
body.home.background_4 {
    background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background4.jpg");
}
body.home.background_5 {
    background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background5.jpg");
}
body.home.background_6 {
    background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background6.jpg");
}
body.home.background_7 {
    background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background7.jpg");
}
```

If you want the background to change on all pages not just the home page remove the .home from the CSS Example:

```
body.background_1 {
        background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background1.jpg");
    }
```

Hope this helps anyone else who is looking :-)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the randomImage Object and the randomImage.generate invocation, inside jQuery .ready() method to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

Also space out ".home" from "body" this queries for "home class" in body

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    var randomImage = {
      paths: [
        "images/home-bg/website-background1.jpg",
        "images/home-bg/website-background2.jpg",
        "images/home-bg/website-background3.jpg",
        "images/home-bg/website-background4.jpg",
        "images/home-bg/website-background5.jpg",
        "images/home-bg/website-background6.jpg",
        "images/home-bg/website-background7.jpg",
      ],
      generate: function(){
        var path = randomImage.paths[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.paths.length)];
        var img = $('<img id="img-responsive">'); // This is Equivalent to $(document.createElement('img'))
        img.attr('src', path);
        img.appendTo('#imagediv'); // The div ID you want to append to
      }
    }

    randomImage.generate();
  });
</script>
```

View on [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMBeMr)

Comment: Hi @Akinjide this did not work. The page is still not loading the background image. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @William I changed the above code using jQuery way of creating an img tag

Answer (score 0):

Just change `body` background like below:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<body>

</body>

<script>
      var randomImage = {
        paths: [          
          "https://www.ricoh.com/r_dc/caplio/r7/img/sample_04.jpg",
          "http://www.riscon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/sample3.jpg",
          "http://cdn6.fonearena.com/i/SonyXperiaZ2CameraSamples/sony-xperia-z2-camera-sample-macro-6.jpg",
          "https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Nikon-D600-Sample-4.jpg",
        ],
        generate: function(){
          var path = randomImage.paths[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.paths.length)];       
          $('body').css('background', 'url('+path+') no-repeat');                     
        }
      }
      randomImage.generate();
</script>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ev9n8czz/1/)

Comment: Hi @Amit this did not work. The page is still not loading the background image. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @William did you checked my "DEMO" link, Its working fine here. Follow my example.